# RedisInsight-v2 always locks ports 5001 and 5002

Tags: redisinsights

According to https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/installing/configurations/, RedisInsight listening port should be

- configurable with the environment variable RIPORT
- default value = 8001

I am running RedisInsight-v2 2.24.0 in Windows 10 and no matter what I do, it always locks ports 5001 and 5002

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm also quite annoyed with this (as port 5001 is commonly used in the ASP.NET core apps which brings some conflicts). So I have checked the RedisInsight source code and found that the port is hard-coded in the code as 5001 and the first available port is used using port-detect package. I haven't found any code reading the value from the RIPORT environment variable.

Comment: However, in [this commit](https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/commit/0ba7e43cf1e4d2e2838c52a6befb431cc5af53b1) the port has been changed to 5530, so in future versions it will not conflict.

Anyway, it seems no setting will be available...

Comment: I have created [a bug report](https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/2224) on the RedisInsigt github repo.